# Hiding member variables in the class diagram generated by pyreverse

Tags: uml, pylint, class-diagram, pyreverse

I have used pyreverse to create class diagrams from python codes.
By default, it shows both the member variables and methods. But usually, I only want to see methods.

If -k option is used, then it will disable both the member variables and methods, so I wonder how to disable only the member variables.